# Como hacer que varios archivos de python se comuniquen entre ellos

Tags: python, variables

Como puedo hacer para que varios archivos de python se comuniquen entre ellos, como por ejemplo en un archivo guardar la variable x=50, y que otro archivo tome esta variable y pueda trabajar, como realizar una suma: print(x+25).

ARCHIVO 1 `x=50`

ARCHIVO 2 `print(x+25)`

Answer (score 1):

**Suponiendo que tenemos un script `programa_a.py` que contiene `print(x+2)` y un script `programa_b.py` que contiene `x=2`**

### Si ambos scripts se encuentran en un mismo directorio

*Estructura de archivos*

```
Proyecto (carpeta)
 | programa_a.py
 | programa_b.py
 |______________
```

*programa_a.py*

```
from programa_b import x

print(x+2)
```

### Si el script a importar se encuentra en un subdirectorio

Si se encuentra en un subdirectorio de la raíz del proyecto será necesario crear un archivo vacío de nombre `__init__.py` en el subdirectorio que contiene el script a importar. Esto para comunicar a Python que debe buscar en esa carpeta los archivos (módulos) que intentas importar:

*Estructura de archivos*

```
Proyecto (carpeta)
 | programa_a.py
 | Modulo_b (carpeta)
 |__| programa_b.py
    | __init__.py
    |________________
```

*programa_a.py*

```
from Modulo_b.programa_b import x

print(x+2)
```

Ambos casos devuelven:

```
4
```

Comment: El segundo caso también puedes resolverlo con `from Modulo_b.programa_b import x`

Comment: es cierto, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

> Crea los dos archivos en la misma carpeta o proyecto

[image]

> Después ubícate en el segundo archivo, ahí importaras todo lo del primer archivo con el código siguiente:

```
from nombre_del_archivo_1 import *
```

[image]

> Así importaras lo del archivo 1 al archivo 2 sin problemas

[image]

Espero que te funcione.
Uso PyCharm para programar.

Comment: Checa [answer].

Comment: No se recomienda usar `from modulo import *`, sino importar sólo los símbolos que vayas a usar. En este caso mejor `from archivo1 import x`. Por otro lado, en este sitio el código debe incluirse como texto delimitado por dos líneas de  ``` en vez de como imágenes.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. 
Apenas ayer hice mi cuenta ._. aún estoy aprendiendo jeje

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo a las respuestas anteriores: Es complicado

De tu pregunta entiendo dos posibilidades:

- Que lo que en realidad buscas es un archivo de configuración que almacene unas constantes que no cambien nunca durante la ejecución de tu(s) programa(s).
- O bien, que haya una comunicación entre procesos de ejecución distintos y que el cambio de una variable en el programa A se refleje en el programa B.

En el primer caso hay infinitud de respuestas, busca "config.py" en google y te llevará por el camino correcto

En el segundo caso es más complicado y tramposo. Necesitarías más conocimientos sobre Python para llevarlo a cabo correctamente, aunque como pista podrías empezar por "pickle" y "sockets" de forma académica (esta no es la manera de empezar en realidad, es solo una "miga de pan")